# how to use a custom endpoint in react admin with nestjs backend

Tags: nestjs, react-admin

I have this endpoint in `nestjs` backend and want to access it from `react-admin`

```
  @Get("/custom-endpoint/:userId")
  async exampleCustomEndpoint(@Param("userId") userId: string) { 
    // do some custom business logic and return response
    return { data: { example: "it works" }};
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple inside of your react component add the following and it will work:

```
import {useDataProvider, useRecordContext} from "react-admin";
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';

 // now inside your React Component add code as below
   const dataProvider = useDataProvider();

  dataProvider.getFilesForUserId = async (userId) => {
    return fetch(`${REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/custom-endpoint/${userId}`, { method: 'GET' })
      .then(response => response.json());
  }

  const {mutate, status, data} = useMutation(
    ['getFilesForUserId', id],
    () => {
      return dataProvider.getFilesForUserId(id)
    }
  );

      console.log('status', status)
      console.log('data', data)
  useEffect(()=>{
    mutate()
  }, [])
```

official documentation: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#adding-custom-methods

#### Update:

Simpler syntax as proposed by Francois in comments below:

```
const MyComponent = ({id}) => {

  const {mutate, status, data} = useMutation(
    [],
    async () => fetch(
      `${REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/custom-endpoint/${id}`,
      {method: 'GET'}
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
  );


  useEffect(() => {
    mutate()
  }, [])

  console.log('status', status)
  console.log('data', data)

  return (<>JSX...</>)
}
```

Comment: Why do you modify the dataProvider if you only need to access the endpoint once? I'd just call fetch() in the useMutation function.

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto, thanks for answering. if I try to destructure fetch from `useMutation` I get this error `TS2339: Property 'fetch' does not exist on type 'UseMutationResult{ data: { fileId: FileData; fileInsurance: FileData; }; }, unknown, void, unknown>'.`

Comment: If meant that:  ```const {mutate, status, data} = useMutation(
    ['getFilesForUserId', id],
    () => fetch(`${REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/custom-endpoint/${idd}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
  );```

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto thanks updated my answer